# mobile broadband is not working on a new laptop,

Tags: laptop, broadband

mobile broadband is not working on a new laptop,

Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen 9
Single OS:Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Terminal commands.
Lsusb=Mobile Broadband not listed.
Lspci= 08:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Quectel Wireless Solutions  Co., Ltd. EM120R-GL LTE Modem.

Am I correct in assuming that the correct driver is not installed?
I have downloaded the propriatory driver from the Lenovo site but have not been able to install it.
Any ideas how I should continue?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep LTE -A3` command.